# Traveling to London with a dismissed misdemeanor

Tags: uk, customs-and-immigration, us-citizens, criminal-records

So  I am US citizen and I want to travel to the UK but I heard you have to wait 12 months after you have gotten off probation. My misdemeanor only came with a fine, but I wanted to get it removed from my record, so I asked for a withheld judgment which they gave me 6 months of unsupervised probation before I could apply to have it dismissed from my record. So my trip date falls 3 months short of a year from the end of that probation. I want to know that since I got the misdemeanor dismissed will that affect me? Should I wait the year or can I go earlier?

Comment: While your conviction is brand new, and the referenced question is regarding an old conviction, I think the answer is still directly relevant here - it doesnt matter that the US consider the conviction to be discharged, you must still disclose it in your UK visa application as they do not discount discharged or dismissed convictions.

Comment: What was the misdemeanour?

Comment: @Moo The suggested dupe is about visa applications, while OP is a non-visa national

Answer (score 5):

> I heard you have to wait 12 months after you have gotten off probation

There are no "have to"'s whatsoever in this regard. You don't get a ban due to probation.

At the end of the day, a single misdemeanour is not normally a cause for concern. To be safe, you could bring documentation about your misdemeanour and probation, and if, by chance, the UK border officers ask about convictions, tell them the truth.

Bottom line: **yes**, you can visit the UK immediately if you want.